# ViewPager and setClipChildren(false) workaround for 2.x devices

Tags: android-viewpager, android-view

I am using Dave Smith's [solution](https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) to make ViewPager behave like an image gallery. My problem is that setClipChildren(false) does not work on devices with 2.x (tried on HTC Desire S and Samsung Galaxy S, both with 2.3.5). Only one image is shown, and scrolling is only inside the viewpager area.

Searching, I have found two solutions:

```
setClipChildren(false);
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

set to the container of the ViewPager, and on the pager, but setLayerType works only on API 11 and up.
and:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I have set this in the manifest, first for my activity and then for the whole app.

Neither of the solutions work for me. 
I know this is a known Android bug: [info here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36788). Do you happen to know a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to call < setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); > on container that is holding the view pager.
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/RIERxUcGpQg