# setClipChildren and hardware layers

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a custom view group that I'm animating around on a screen based on touch events (drag and drop, for instance).

I want it to be able to draw slightly outside its bounds, and still animate smoothly.

I tried setting setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null) on the dragging view, and performance was great, but anything outside the bounds was clipped.

I tried setting LAYER_TYPE_NONE, performance was still fine, but there was animation ghosting/streaking where the view had been dragged (as if it were smearing the screen).

Tried this on a Moto X and Nexus 4, same results.

What's the best way to approach this? Is setClipChildren(false) supposed to work with LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE? Interestingly, LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE exhibits the same unexpected clipping as does LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE.

Comment: To avoid ghosting try invalidating the rectangle that was occupied by the view you are dragging before the drag inside the container

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use following combination:

```
setClipChildren(false);
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

As described here: [ViewPager and setClipChildren(false) workaround for 2.x devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495344/viewpager-and-setclipchildrenfalse-workaround-for-2-x-devices)

Comment: Definitely want the activity to be hardware accelerated though - isn't that sort of a big deal for most apps with a lot of moving Ui elements?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when doing exactly the same thing.  I wanted a drop shadow beneath my views.  The problem is that the system will only clean up the rectangle left by the view you have moved and since you are rendering outside that view by choosing to not clip children, the rectangle is not covering all of your tracks and remains of the rendered view leave a smudgy sort of mess behind.

The solution I used was to put the view I wanted to move inside another view (A RelativeLayout with the child view aligned to the parent's center) that is slightly larger and does cover the drop shadow or whatever else you are rendering outside the bounds of your child.  You can set the background of that parent view to transparent/clear.  Now attach the drag action to your parent view and the Rect that is cleaned up behind it will also clean up the child's mess.

The only other way I found to do it which was very costly in terms of performance was to re-render the views that show the mess at each frame.  I couldn't find any other solutions.

Comment: That's useful in explaining why this works without a hardware layer, but I think using the hardware layer is pretty critical on some devices. Am I off base here?

Comment: Using hardware acceleration is automatically on for Android versions above level 14 anyway.  The solution I'm offering should work with hardware acceleration on or off but to be honest, I've seen far more issues with hardware acceleration on than I have with it off.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but without hardware layers, most dragging/moving operations I've tried noticeably drop frames on something like an S3.

Also, isn't this answer just a variation of "don't use setClipChildren"? If I didn't clip children, there wouldn't be any problem in the first place, no?

Comment: No, I'm saying do allow your child to render outside its bounds, but nest it inside a larger parent view which is transparent and large enough to accommodate the content outside the bounds of the child, then move the parent for the desired effect. I know this works because I use that exact trick in an app soon to be released for a decorating app where you can move photos, colour chips and text around with shadow outside their bounds.

Comment: This is working. I used FrameLayout and gave it a fixed width and height instead of wrap_conent, and voilà.